# AppBar full transparent

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, appbar, flutter-appbar

### Problem

> Is there any way to make the `AppBar` **fully transparent** without
> using the `Stack` Widget??
>
> This is my `AppBar` right now (*It's transparent but not fully, it has a
> little white shadow*)

```
AppBar(
  automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
  backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(0, 255, 255, 255).withOpacity(0.1),
  shadowColor: const Color.fromARGB(0, 255, 255, 255).withOpacity(0.1),
  title: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: [
      Row(
        children: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {}, 
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.menu,
              color: colors.BLACK,
              size: 24,
            ),
          ),
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {}, 
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.notifications,
              color: colors.BLACK,
              size: 24,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      Row(
        children: const [
          Text('Location', style: TextStyle(color: colors.BLACK, fontSize: 14)),
          Icon(
            Icons.location_on,
            color: colors.BLACK,
            size: 24,
          ),
        ]
      ),
      IconButton(
        onPressed: () {}, 
        icon: const CircleAvatar(
          backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/icons/temp_profile_pic.png'),
          radius: 20,
        )
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

### Prints

Here some prints to show you what's happening:

Scroll on top

[image: Scroll on top]

When scrolled

[image: When scrolled]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set your AppBar completely transparent you need to set the `elevation` to `0` and set the color as `transparent`, as:

```
AppBar(
   backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
   elevation: 0
)
```

The AppBar will have the same color as the Scaffold's background.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

add these properties to the app bar

```
backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
elevation: 0,
shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
surfaceTintColor: Colors.transparent,
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer did not work for me, and did not consider foreground colour for things like screen title or action buttons.

This is what I used:

```dart
Scaffold(
  // height of the body is extended to include the height of the AppBar
  // and the top of the body is aligned with the top of the AppBar.
  extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
  appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    foregroundColor: Colors.black,
    elevation: 0,
  ), // AppBar
  ...
);
```