# How to make bottom app bar to transparent

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

i want to build a blur effect on my modal bottom screen with bottomNavigationBar property, i already set the LinearGradient color with 0.5 opacity and extendBody: true in scaffold but nothing works, the blur in the modal just won't go transparent

[image]

> this is the build widget

```
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: kWhiteGreyColor,
      extendBody: true,
      bottomNavigationBar:_buildSeeMore(),
    );
  }
```

> this is the blur widget

```
  Widget _buildSeeMore() {
return Container(
  width: double.infinity,
  height: 315,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    gradient: LinearGradient(
      begin: Alignment.topCenter,
      end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      colors: [
        kWhiteColor.withOpacity(0.5),
        kWhiteColor,
      ],
    ),
  ),
  child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
    children: [
      TextButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Text(
          'See More',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: kBlueColor,
            fontSize: 16,
            fontWeight: semiBold,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}

Comment: It is not quite the same, but maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72203905/appbar-full-transparent/72203947#72203947) could help you.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do blur effect please use backDropFilter widget and in container give color transparent

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).